# How to know group and artifact ID's while adding to maven

Tags: java, maven

Trying to add JNA dependency to my java project, but don't know Group and Artifact ID's and version number. What is the logic of getting such kind of information in general? Is it possible somehow browse for this information? For example I don't know what JNA versions are available.

Comment: It is literally the first google result: https://www.google.de/search?q=jna+maven+dependency

Comment: Usually the first result googling "______ maven dependency" is the maven  repo w/ the dependencies. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna

Comment: I usually google for examples/documentation to find group+artifact IDs, and then use http://mvnrepository.com/ to search for available versions. I periodically go back to the latter location to look for newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

I usually check Maven Coordinates here: http://search.maven.org/

You can even search for a specific class: http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of reverse index to get maven id from class, but you can :

1. type the root package or emblematic class in google and find a jar that contains it (grepcode.com usually does that, or you will find the github page of the project)
2. search with jar name on maven central